# SQL/MYSQL - Filtering items in one table by their effects in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the effects of items that verify some conditions. Being given that the effects are stored in the rows of a second table.

> Table 1 structure : `id,itemId,itemName,typeName,level`
>
> Table 2 structure : `id, effectId, itemId, effectName, min,max`

The main issue I face is that some effects are worth others with a specific ratio, which my conditions must reflect.

Best query I built so far :

```
SELECT i.name,i.level,i.typeName
FROM `effects` AS e,`items` AS i
WHERE `effectId` IN (111,125,126,138) AND i.itemId=e.itemId AND i.typeId IN (1) AND (`level` BETWEEN 150 AND 200)
GROUP BY i.itemId
HAVING count(distinct `effectId`) >= 3
ORDER BY SUM(CASE e.effectId WHEN 138 THEN e.max*0.2 ELSE e.max END) 
DESC,i.level DESC
```

The two mains issues i have with this query is that I can't explicit MUST HAVE conditions as well as equivalences : the items can have `111 and 125 and 126 but no 138`, while the must have are `138, 125 or 111,  126 or 111`.

EDIT : The requested item must have 138,126 and 125, but 111 can add up or replace both 126 or 125.
So one correct item can have :
(138,126,125,111)
(138,126,111)
(138,125,111)
(138,126,125)
(138,111)

I can order the results but I have to make others queries to get the effects values which doesn't keep the order of the first query.

I hope I've been factual enough, if you need more information please ask.
Thanks you for reading.

Comment: Sometimes when you simplify your question as simple as possible, it gets attention. Some people really don't like plenty grammar and for that matter they don't get attracted to such question. If you could revised your question as preferred on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I think it might get attention.

Comment: I did simplify, do you think that will be enough ? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand. You are looking for items (with type 1 and level 150-200) that have at least one effect of the set (111, 125,128) and at least one effect of the set (111,126)? So an item with only 111 would be fine, an item with only 125 and 126 would be fine too, wheras an item with only 125 and 128 would not be desired. Correct?

Comment: Who taught you this join syntax by the way? It was used in the 1980s, but then it was made redundant in 1992. We use explicit ANSI joins today (e.g. `from effects e inner join items i on i.itemid = e.itemid`).

Comment: I found this syntax in some other stackoverflow question ^^
In this example, 111 give as much power that 125 or 126. The requested item must have 138,126 and 125, but 111 can add up or replace both 126 or 125. 
So one correct item can have  : 
- (138,126,125,111) - (138,126,111), (138,125,111),(138,126,125), (138,111)

Comment: Ah, I see. Is `itemid` + `effectid` unique in `effects` or can it happen that I find the same effect twice for the same item in the table?

Comment: It can happens but only for one type of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thorsten Kettner really helped me find the answer i was looking for, by showing me the right syntax and the possibilities offered by the HAVING keyword.

I wanted to filter items from their table by their effects stored in a second table, and then show the effects of the selected items.

The complexity came from the fact that one effect can have an opposite effect, and an equivalent effect (or more) with a specific ratio.

In the end, it just takes to SUM all those with a Case, then add the SUM to the SELECT, the HAVING and the ORDER BY (but for the ORDER BY you SUM all the effects which are separated in the SELECT and the HAVING).

Here is one example of a php built query :

```
SELECT i.name, i.level, i.typeName,
    SUM(CASE e.effectId WHEN 178 THEN e.max WHEN 179 THEN -1*e.max END) as effect,
    SUM(CASE e.effectId WHEN 126 THEN e.max WHEN 155 THEN -1*e.max WHEN 138 THEN 1*e.max  END) as effect2
FROM items i
JOIN effects e ON e.itemId = i.itemId
WHERE i.typeId IN ('16') 
    AND i.level BETWEEN 1 AND 200
    AND e.effectId IN (178,126,155,138)
GROUP BY i.itemId
HAVING
    SUM(CASE e.effectId WHEN 178 THEN e.max WHEN 179 THEN -1*e.max END) > 0 
    AND SUM(CASE e.effectId WHEN 126 THEN e.max WHEN 155 THEN -1*e.max WHEN 138 THEN 1*e.max  END) >0 
ORDER BY SUM(CASE e.effectId WHEN 178 THEN e.max WHEN 179 THEN -1*e.max WHEN 126 THEN e.max WHEN 155 THEN -1*e.max WHEN 138 THEN 1*e.max   END),
i.level DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Thanks a lot Thorsten Kettner !

Answer (score 0):

I'll recap: The item must both

- have effect 138
- have effect 111 OR both 125 and 126

So the `HAVING` clause must put this into practice:

```
SELECT i.name, i.level, i.typeName
FROM items i
JOIN effects e ON e.itemId = i.itemId
WHERE i.typeId IN (1) 
  AND i.level BETWEEN 150 AND 200
  AND e.effectId IN (111,125,126,138)
GROUP BY i.itemId
HAVING SUM(e.effectId = 138) > 0
AND
(
  SUM(e.effectId = 111) > 0 
  OR 
  (SUM(e.effectId = 125) > 0 AND SUM(e.effectId = 126) > 0)
)
ORDER BY SUM(CASE e.effectId WHEN 138 THEN e.max*0.2 ELSE e.max END) DESC, i.level DESC;
```

This makes use of MySQL's true = 1 / false = 0.